# Building an XML Document with Nokogiri Subclasses

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm attempting to use Nokogiri to create an XML document that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0" ID="OSU147123651" entityID="urn:mace:incommon:osu.edu" validUntil="2016-07-02T10:00:01Z">
  <ContactPerson contactType="administrative">
    <GivenName>Authentication Support</GivenName>
    <EmailAddress>webauth-admin@lists.service.ohio-state.edu</EmailAddress>
  </ContactPerson>
  ...
</EntityDescriptor>
```

I've created a `Wmc::Builder` class which inherits from `Nokogiri::XML::Builder`. This works well but I want to create a `Wmc::EntityDescriptor` class that I can then insert into my document.

```
class Wmc::Builder < Nokogiri::XML::Builder
  PROLOG = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone ="no"?>'

  def initialize(entities = {})
    super({}, Nokogiri::XML(PROLOG)) do |xml|
      # something goes here...
    end
  end
end
```

What Nokogiri class should I subclass and what is the correct way to insert this into my main document?

Comment: Instead of a link to the data necessary for the program, insert the minimal example XML into your question plus the smallest matching example of your desired output. Links rot then break making your question worthless to those searching for a similar solution in the future.  Read "[mcve]" and "[ask]" including the linked pages.

Comment: I've updated my post to include a chunk of the XML. Thanks for `linking` me to those pages ;)